# paginEnabled prop in react-native-reanimated-carousel does not works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, pagination

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import Carousel, { ICarouselInstance } from 'react-native-reanimated-carousel';
import { CarouselProps } from './CarouselComponent.types';
import { Icon } from '../Icon/Icon';
import { Typography } from '../Typography/Typography';
import { TypographyVariant } from '../Typography/Typography.types';
import { getScreenWidth } from '~endo45/helpers/screenSize';
import { ColorPalette } from '~endo45/config';

export function CarouselComponent({ carouselItems }: CarouselProps) {
    const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    const ref = React.useRef<ICarouselInstance>(null);
    const baseOptions = {
        vertical: false,
        width: width * 0.85,
        height: getScreenWidth(60)

    } as const;
    return (
        <View>
            <Carousel
                {...baseOptions}
                loop={false}
                ref={ref}
                style={styles.carousel}
                data={carouselItems}
                pagingEnabled
                renderItem={({ index }) => (
                    <View style={[styles.itemContainer, carouselItems[index].customContainerStyle]}>
                        <View style={[{ backgroundColor: carouselItems[index].iconProps?.color }, styles.iconbackground]}>
                            <Icon {...carouselItems[index].iconProps} />
                        </View>
                        <Typography text={carouselItems[index].title} variant={TypographyVariant.LARGE_TEXT_BOLD} />
                        <Typography text={carouselItems[index].desc} variant={TypographyVariant.LARGE_TEXT} />
                    </View>
                )}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    carousel: {
        width: '100%',
    },
    itemContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        marginLeft: '2.5%',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: ColorPalette.Transparent,
        borderRadius: getScreenWidth(6),
        padding: getScreenWidth(6),
        backgroundColor: ColorPalette.White,
    },
    iconbackground: {
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderRadius: 50,
        marginBottom: getScreenWidth(4),
    },
});
```

This is my code where I used react-native-reanimated-carousel. And, for pagination, I am using pagingEnabled prop as mentioned in thier docs.

The pagination is not displayed even after adding this prop. Is there any other way, without using any other library, to display pagination.

Thanks in advance.